# How are you able to create partially initialised structs?

Tags: rust

When creating a struct in Rust it seems like it's difficult to create one without having all of the fields set. For example with the following code

```
struct Connection {
    url: String,
    stream: TcpStream
}
```

You aren't able to set `url` without giving `stream` as well.

```
// Compilation error asking for 'stream'
let m = Connection { url: "www.google.com".to_string() };
```

How are you able to create these references that might be `Option<None>` until a later time?

The best I have found is using the `Default` trait, but I'd rather not have to create the `TcpStream` until a later time than when the struct is initialised. Am I able to do this with something like a `Box`?

Comment: *it seems like it's difficult to create one without having all of the fields set* => Actually, it's impossible in safe Rust: the compiler keeps you honest.

Comment: And this is *a good thing*. No more accidentally using things that are NULL! Even better, no more accidentally using things that aren't NULL but also aren't initialized!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One thing you can do is to wrap the `TcpStream` in an `Option`, i.e. `Option<TcpStream>`. When you first construct the struct, it'll be `None`, and when you initialize it you make it `self.stream = Some(<initialize tcp stream>)`. Wherever you use the `TCPStream`, you'll have to check if it's `Some`, i.e. if it has already been initialized. If you can guarantee your behavior then you can just `unwrap()`, but it's probably better to make a check anyways.

```
struct Connection {
    url: String,
    stream: Option<TcpStream>
}

impl Connection {
    pub fn new() -> Connection {
        Connection {
            url: "www.google.com".to_string(),
            stream: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn initialize_stream(&mut self) {
        self.stream = Some(TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:34254").unwrap());
    }

    pub fn method_that_uses_stream(&self) {
        if let Some(ref stream) = self.stream {
            // can use the stream here
        } else {
            println!("the stream hasn't been initialized yet");
        }
    }
}
```

This is similar to what is done in Swift, in case you're familiar with that language.

Comment: Can someone explain the syntax of `if let Some(ref mut stream) = self.stream {`?

Comment: Sure. That should've just been `ref stream`, I've fixed it. It just means that a reference to the stream within the `Option` is obtained, rather than the moving the value entirely. For further information, check out [the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html).

Answer (score 6):

As an extension to [Jorge Israel Peña's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30389229/155423), you can use a *builder*. The builder has all the optional fields and produces the final value without `Option`s:

```rust
use std::net::TcpStream;

struct ConnectionBuilder {
    url: String,
    stream: Option<TcpStream>,
}

impl ConnectionBuilder {
    fn new(url: impl Into<String>) -> Self {
        Self {
            url: url.into(),
            stream: None,
        }
    }

    fn stream(mut self, stream: TcpStream) -> Self {
        self.stream = Some(stream);
        self
    }

    fn build(self) -> Connection {
        let url = self.url;
        let stream = self
            .stream
            .expect("Perform actual error handling or default value");
        Connection { url, stream }
    }
}

struct Connection {
    url: String,
    stream: TcpStream,
}

impl Connection {
    fn method_that_uses_stream(&self) {
        // can use self.stream here
    }
}
```

This means that you don't have to litter your code with checks to see if the stream has been set yet.

See also:

- [How to initialize a struct with a series of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44170735/155423)
- [Do Rust builder patterns have to use redundant struct code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43840415/155423)
- [Is it possible to create a macro to implement builder pattern methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38158167/155423)
- [How to write an idiomatic build pattern with chained method calls in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41617182/155423)

Answer (score 4):

All fields indeed have to be initialized when creating the `struct` instance (there is no *null* in Rust) so all the memory is allocated.
There is often a dedicated method (like `new`) that sets default values for fields which are supposed to be modified at a later stage.

I'd use the `Box` when you don't know the size of the field (like `Vec` does).