# Is it possible to create a macro to implement builder pattern methods?

Tags: rust

I have a [builder pattern](https://aturon.github.io/ownership/builders.html) implemented for my struct:

```
pub struct Struct {
    pub grand_finals_modifier: bool,
}
impl Struct { 
    pub fn new() -> Struct {
        Struct {
            grand_finals_modifier: false,
        }
    }

    pub fn grand_finals_modifier<'a>(&'a mut self, name: bool) -> &'a mut Struct {
        self.grand_finals_modifier = grand_finals_modifier;
        self
    }
}
```

Is it possible in Rust to make a macro for methods like this to generalize and avoid a lot of duplicating code? Something that we can use as the following:

```
impl Struct {
    builder_field!(hello, bool);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/macros.html), I've come up with this code:

```
macro_rules! builder_field {
    ($field:ident, $field_type:ty) => {
        pub fn $field<'a>(&'a mut self,
                          $field: $field_type) -> &'a mut Self {
            self.$field = $field;
            self
        }
    };
}

struct Struct {
    pub hello: bool,
}
impl Struct {
    builder_field!(hello, bool);
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = Struct {
        hello: false,
    };
    s.hello(true);
    println!("Struct hello is: {}", s.hello);
}
```

It does exactly what I need: creates a public builder method with specified name, specified member and type.

Answer (score 4):

To complement the already accepted answer, since it is 4 years old by now, you should check out the crate [rust-derive-builder](https://github.com/colin-kiegel/rust-derive-builder). It uses procedural macros to automatically implement the builder pattern for any struct.